# How can I show a memory address in QLabel?

Tags: qt

I wanted to show a memory address in a QLabel. When I compile the following code, it give me error:

```
// Allocate space for our DLL path inside the target remote process.
            LPVOID dll_path_in_remote_mem_addr = VirtualAllocEx(
                        target_process,
                        NULL,
                        _MAX_PATH,
                        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT,
                        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE
                        );

            if (dll_path_in_remote_mem_addr == NULL) {
                QMessageBox::warning(this, "Failed OPS", "Allocating space for our DLL path in the remote target process's virtual memory space failed...");
                CloseHandle(target_process);
            }
            else
            {
                ui->labelDllAllocationAddress->setText(&dll_path_in_remote_mem_addr);
            }
```

After compilation process, it shows me the following error:

> error: C2664: 'void QLabel::setText(const QString &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPVOID *' to 'const QString &'

How can I show a memory address of LPVOID type in widget like QLabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert your address to a QString type. As it is an address, you probably want to see it in its hexadecimal form :

**EDIT** : as the LPVOID value is not implicitly cast to an int, you need to do it yourself.
**EDIT2** : the long type is not big enough to hold the pointer (64-bit machine), so you need to use long long.

```
unsigned long address = reinterpret_cast<long long>(dll_path_);
QString addressInTextValue = QString("%1").arg(address, 0, 16);
```

This is documented here : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

Comment: It gives me following error: error: C2664: 'QString QString::arg(const QString &,const QString &,const QString &,const QString &,const QString &,const QString &,const QString &,const QString &,const QString &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'LPVOID' to 'qlonglong'

Comment: @lightning I'm not familiar with windows types such as LPVOID, but as it is a pointer, you should always be able to cast it to an integer value. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, after cast it gives me the following warning: warning: C4311: 'reinterpret_cast': pointer truncation from 'LPVOID' to 'int'. Also, the address seems not correct, it gives me an address like integer i.e. 300000.

Comment: @lightning Edited the answer again. The correct integer type is long long, you are using a 64-bit machine and the pointer type does not fit in a simple long.